# How to validate rest template XML response against xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd-validation

In my spring boot rest api I am invoking an external rest api and getting XML response. Now I want to validate the response against an xsd. The xsd contain is defined in application.properties file. How to achieve this? Any suggestions or code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: This is not seem a Spring question, is it? It's more of "how to validate xml with xsd in java" https://www.google.com/search?q=java+validate+xml+against+xsd (also I'd suggest to update your tags, that increases the chance of receiving an answer). Another thing, very soon people start asking you to show what you have done so far. Do it before it's too late.

Comment: I have edited the tag. The examples i see over internet , basically validates an xml against an xsd, where both of these are stored in file system. In my case , i get the xml from service call and then want to validate it against an xsd which should come from property file.

Comment: Can you share us an example of your code? Including the property file and your Java code (what you did so far)